# Show Release and Stages from within Bug or PBI Detail Page

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

Our workitems are currently linked with their commits, PR and builds they are integrated in. Now we would like to know if a PBI or Bug is already deployed and if so, to which environment.

When we click on a specific Release, we can already see all the work (bugs/pbi/tasks) that have been done in this release.
But we would like to see that from the other side, coming from the workitem....

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.

Our workitems are already linked to builds and releases. That was never a problem.

The Development section on the detail page is just not showing up that link type. Only linked builds, commits and pull requests. If I navigate to **Links**, then I'm able see all available link types, including *"integrated in release environment"*:

[image]

[image]

---

### UPDATE:

With sprint 158 Update of Azure DevOps, the preview of the new Deployment control on the work item form has been introduced:

[image]

This control links your work items to a release and enables you to easily track where your work item has been deployed. To learn more see the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/work-item-deployments-control?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning on the automatic linking in the options of the build/release pipeline?

[image]
[image]

Comment: We have turned on both options. Workitems are linked with the build, but not with the release.